# How to extract motion vector from mpeg video

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg

I need motion vectors of a mpeg video in a text format.  I referred to the [link](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=172767) which says extract_mvs.c can be used to do so. But I am not able to execute the program because of so many header file dependency errors. Visualization of MVs is pretty easy using ffmpeg command. Getting the actual MVs of each frame is my requirement. Could you please guide me to extract motion vectors in their raw format.

Comment: what are you planning to do with the extracted data?

Answer (score 1):

After compiling *extract_mvs.c* try this command:

```
./extract_mvs input.mp4 > output.txt
```

It should extract the motion vectors into txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Try [MV-Tractus](https://github.com/jishnujayakumar/MV-Tractus). This tool will give you motion vectors in the form of JSON for every frame. In addition to this, the frames extracted by this tool can be used with openCV's cv2.imshow('Frame', frame), where the frame is the actual CV Mat Object.

This tool is a polyglot provided in a wide range of languages like C, C++ and Python. This makes it even more usable by a wider range of audience.